# regex - notepad++ - search for a string containing a string and not containing another string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am not able to solve this:
I have text file with some entries like "user = ABname".
I would like to search for all the lines containing user id not beginning with "AB" or "ab" and I need to do it with a regular exp using the search functionality of Notepad++.
I have tried using

```
user = ^[ab]
```

but actually is not working as expected.

I should find all these:

```
user = CDname1
user = cdname2
user = acname3
user = xbname4
```

but not

```
user = abname1
user = ABname2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using negative look ahead:

```
user = (?![aA][bB]).*
```

You are misunderstand how a character class works. The character class - `[ab]` matches only one character, out of all present inside `[` and `]`. So, it will match either `a` or `b`. I won't match `ab` in sequence. Basically
`[ab]` is same as `a|b`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a negative lookahead, such as:

```
^user = (?![Aa][Bb])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `^user = ([aA][^bB].*|[^a].*)`

It looks for `user =` then either: `a` followed by anything that's not `b` or "anything that doesn't start with an `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 user = (?:[^a]|a(?!b))\S+
```

*(don't check the case insensitive box, but check the regex box:)*